# Dockerfile COPY command doesn't make my file available with I run the image

Tags: dockerfile, copy

I am using Linux Ubuntu 20.04, Pycharm Pro, Python 3.9, Docker (installed a couple weeks ago, don't remember ver).

I have a Python project in the path (
`/home/crusty.user/PythonProjects/NoLegals`
There are 4 files in this path: main.py, utils.py, NoLegals_Config.csv, Dockerfile

The csv file acts as a config to tell the python project which parts of the research to do, or not to.  It reads a line, with a Y or N.  Pretty simple.  It works great in Linux and in windows.

From the path above, I run sudo docker build -t nolegals .
Everything runs successfully.

When I try to run the Dockerfile (sudo docker run nolegals) it fails when it gets to the csv file with the error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/crusty.user/PythonProjects/NoLegals/NoLegals_Config.csv'`

In my Dockerfile I have:

```
WORKDIR /NoLegals
```

Further down I have:

```
COPY NoLegals_Config.csv /
COPY main.py /
COPY utils.py /
```

--There's a bunch of otherstuff for setting up the environment, libraries, etc. all of which runs successfully on the build.  Also, I don't get a failure regarding the path of the csv file during build.  I've been digging around and I've learned that it might having something to do with not being able to find the csv file within the Docker image when it builds, but it finds the main.py and utils.py just fine.  There is a line of code in the Python main.py file that points to the location of the csv file dynamically as a suggestion to fix the problem but this too has failed.  The path the error prints is also the correct path to the csv file.

```
#this works in linux, just not in the Dockerfile
filename = r'NoLegals_Config.csv
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
print(filepath)
```

I've tried LOTS of different things in that COPY NoLegals_config.csv / line, but to no avail.  I appreciate any suggestions.

I've tried various forms of the COPY. Previous to the one listed was using the syntax:
`COPY <source-path> <destination-Path> COPY NoLegals_Config.csv / COPY <full path of source> </NoLegals/NoLegals_Config.csv>`

I've tried some other things that I can't recall.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was fully qualifying the COPY statements.

```
WORKDIR /NoLegals

COPY NoLegals_Config.csv /NoLegals/NoLegals_Config.csv
COPY main.py /NoLegals/main.py
COPY utils.py /NoLegals/utils.py

CMD ["python"."/NoLegals/main.py"]
```

Is there a simpler way I could have written this?